# how to get selected column name or index in WPF Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Can you please tell how to get selected column name or index in WPF  Grid.

Comment: Do you mean GridView or DataGrid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how we can get the value of a specific cell

```
Object obj = GetCell(3).Content;
                     string cellContent = String.Empty;
                     if (obj != null)
                     {
                         if (obj is TextBox)
                             cellContent = ((TextBox)(obj)).Text;
                         else
                             cellContent = ((TextBlock)(obj)).Text;
                      }




private DataGridCell GetCell(int column)
    {
        DataGridRow rowContainer = GetRow();

        if (rowContainer != null)
        {
            DataGridCellsPresenter presenter = GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(rowContainer);

            // Try to get the cell but it may possibly be virtualized.
            DataGridCell cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column);
            if (cell == null)
            {
                // Now try to bring into view and retreive the cell.
                customDataGrid.UCdataGridView.ScrollIntoView(rowContainer, customDataGrid.UCdataGridView.Columns[column]);
                cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column);
            }
            return cell;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

For the DataGrid, the column you can get via the CurrentCell-property:

```
DataGridCellInfo cellInfo = dataGrid.CurrentCell;
DataGridColumn column=cellInfo.Column;
```

Comment: @Abhishek: Are we talking about System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid? Or do you mean System.Windows.Controls.Grid. This one has no selection capabilities. It's only a layout container. Can you post the exact type name of your Grid-Control. Maybe then I can help you...

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get a list of rows selected:

```
IList rows = dg.SelectedItems;
```

From [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121186/datagrid-get-selected-rows-column-values).