# WPF: How to get cell value from DataGridRow

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have `DataGridRow` of a `DataGrid`, how can I get the individual column values from it? See the code below.

```
var itemsSource = MESearchDatagrid.ItemsSource as IEnumerable;
if (itemsSource != null)
{
    foreach (var item in itemsSource)
    {
        var row = MESearchDatagrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as DataGridRow;
        if (row != null)
        {
        //How to get the Cell value?
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I am using WPF.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF Datagrid Get Selected Cell Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19225568/wpf-datagrid-get-selected-cell-value)

Comment: Can you post the XAML too please ?

Answer (score 2):

You can cast your row.item to your initial class type.

```
        var itemsSource = MESearchDatagrid.ItemsSource;
        if (itemsSource != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in itemsSource)
            {
                var row = MESearchDatagrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as DataGridRow;
                if (row != null)
                {
                    var data = row.Item as UserClass;
                    MessageBox.Show(data.Name);
                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason to call the `ContainerFromItem` method here. The `ItemsSource` contains the actual data objects. You only need to cast them to your type (called `YourClass` in the following sample code):

```
var itemsSource = MESearchDatagrid.ItemsSource as IEnumerable;
if (itemsSource != null)
{
    foreach (var item in itemsSource.OfType<YourClass>())
    {
        var prop = item.Property1;
        //...
    }
}
```

`Property1` is a property of `YourClass`.