# Get the multiple selected Row in data-grid in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpfdatagrid, wpftoolkit

I want to get the multiple selection of data-grid in WPF, as my the business requirement I have a customer table in data grid which allows multiple selection and radio button (ALL, Selected, All but selected). If the selected or all but selected is clicked the I have to pull data only for those customers which are selected in the data- grid. Please advice solution to get multiple selected row of data grid.

Thanks.

Comment: No, currently I not using MVVM.

Comment: Can you show some of your code? It's a bit difficult to give you an example of how this could be done without knowing what you currently have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have got a solution for the above question,

```
//CustomerDTO is the DTO class which has all the column names of Customer Table.
//dgUsers is the data grid.
List<CustomerDTO> customerList ;
for (int i = 0; i < dgUsers.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
{
customerList.Add((CustomerDTO)dgUsers.SelectedItems[i]);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: and for remove item from list : 
`var unSelected = grdItems.SelectedItem as Class;    list.Remove(unSelected);` if used check box Un_Checked event.

Answer (score 2):

There are many stackoverflow posts concerning this problem.
Following are two posts which describe how to get the selected items.

Code behind approach: [DataGrid get selected rows' column values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5121363/1108036)

MVVM approach: [Bind to SelectedItems from DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9880673/1108036)