# Get multi-selection in Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm trying to get all row selected in a datagrid. All row are an item of an `ObservableCollection<T>`, and I would like to know which elements are, or not, selected (could be one, lots or none). Also, I don't want to use a checkbox, would like (if possible) somethink like ctrl + leftMouseClick so select multiple rows.

Here is the xaml code :

```
                <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ListBinded}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="ListName"
                Style="{StaticResource AzureDataGrid}" Grid.Row="1" FrozenColumnCount="2"
                ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                    <DataGrid.Resources>
                        <Style x:Key="AlignBottomColumnHeader" BasedOn="{StaticResource AzureDataGridColumnHeader}" TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Bottom" />
                        </Style>
                    </DataGrid.Resources>
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <!--Description-->
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Description" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource AlignBottomColumnHeader}" Width="*" MinWidth="200">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Border BorderThickness="2">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding InfoColumn}"/>
                                    </Border>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

Would love to put the C# code below, but there is no code for now.

EDIT: For me it's not a duplicate, because I don't have a DataGrid in my code below but a ObservableCollection, which does not have a SelectedItem parameter (i'm trying to get the informations in the ViewModelBase class, after an ICommand triggered)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the multiple selected Row in data-grid in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22143202/get-the-multiple-selected-row-in-data-grid-in-wpf)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the MVVM pattern you can bind a `SelectedRecord` property of your VM with `SelectedItem` of the `DataGrid`. By this method you always have `SelectedValue` in your VM.

If you are not using MVVM you can get `SelectedIndex` property of `DataGrid` and then cast it to the type you have. Then you can loop over it to get all selected items.

Comment: The problem I get is that I don't have a datagrid in the below code but an ObservableCollection<T>

Comment: What do you mean the code you showed, has a datagrid (otherwise how do you expect to show your data), you can just give it a name by x:Name = "MyDataGrid" and do as I told you there.

Comment: I already did that, and I can't access to MyDataGrid in my ViewModelBase class