# Getting value from SelectedItem RadGridView

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, radgridview

I'm using this List:

`List<AssetListData> assetList = new List<AssetListData>();`

Filled with data, and bind it to my `RadGridView` using this code:

```
AssetList_GridView.ItemsSource = assetList;
```

And now I have a `GridView` with two columns (`Name` and `Type`). I created a `ContextMenu` in `AssetList_GridView` consists of `Edit` and `Delete`. I need to get the value after I click the `ContextMenu` but it failed. I tried this code inside the click event in `ContextMenu` :

```
private void GridContextMenu_ItemClick(object sender, Telerik.Windows.RadRoutedEventArgs e)
{
        MenuItem item = (e.OriginalSource as RadMenuItem).DataContext as MenuItem;
        switch (item.Text)
        {
            case "Edit Asset":
                var typeValue = ((assetListData)AssetList_GridView.SelectedItem).assetType;
                this.AssetList_GridView.BeginEdit();
                break;
            case "Delete Asset":
                this.AssetList_GridView.Items.Remove(this.AssetList_GridView.SelectedItem);
                break;
        }
}
```

The error from `var typeValue = ((assetListData)AssetList_GridView.SelectedItem).assetType;` said that:

> assetList could not be found.

Why can't I access `assetList` here, but I can access it for `GridView` `ItemsSource`?
Is there any simple way to get value from the clicked row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SelectedItem cant be retyped to LIST, if you want to retype it you should use

```
var typeValue = ((AssetListData)AssetList_GridView.SelectedItem).assetType;
```

Comment: the error is still the same, i'll edit my question to make it more detail

Comment: ah nvm i need to write all the directory of the AssetListData eventho i made it before. thanks

Comment: Sir, what if i want to get both assetName and assetType? and what if i have more and want to get all the value in that Row?

Comment: you can do var row = (AssetListData)AssetList_GridView.SelectedItem and you get whole ROW but not sure if that will work.

Otherwise look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121186/datagrid-get-selected-rows-column-values