# Get selected Datagrid's row data off of Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, textbox

I want to get the data every column from a datagrid connected to an Entity Framework database.
I want to cast them to their respective Textboxes but I can't seemingly draw the data from the datagrid.

Here's the code I am using at first ([saw it here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121186/datagrid-get-selected-rows-column-values)):

```
 private void DataGridCamiao_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGrid DataGridCamiao = sender as DataGrid;
        DataRowView row = (DataRowView)DataGridCamiao.SelectedItems[0];
        TextBoxMarca.Text = row["Marca"].ToString();
    }
```

Though after running it gives me an error:

> System.InvalidCastException: Cannot associate *(my custom type)* to *DataRowView*

I've read about it and I've changed it to my custom type, to which it says it can't be indexed and does not run, which basically left me stumped as I tried other methods. I'd like some insight on what I'm doing wrong here, maybe different ways to achieve the same goal and I forwardly thank anyone trying to help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should cast the `SelectedItem` property to your entity type:

```
private void DataGridCamiao_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid DataGridCamiao = sender as DataGrid;
    if (DataGridCamiao.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        var item = DataGridCamiao.SelectedItem as YourEntityClass;
        if (item != null)
            TextBoxMarca.Text = item.Marca;
    }
}
```

Change `YourEntityClass` to the name of your entity type, i.e. the type `T` of the `IEnumerable<T>` that you have set or bind to the `ItemsSource` property of the `DataGrid`.

Comment: Oh goodness, thank you so much. It worked now, and it's been killing my head for the past 72 hours. Thanks so much for helping an underslept college student :p

Answer (score 0):

you can do the same without code-behind:

```
<DataGrid Name="DataGridCamiao">
    <!--columns, attributes, etc here-->
</DataGrid>

<TextBox Name="TextBoxMarca" 
         Text="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.Marca, ElementName=DataGridCamiao}"/>
```

and it is even better to switch to MVVM approach and bind both DataGrid.SelectedItem and TextBox.Text to view model properties.