# DataGridView C# wpf select row to textboxes

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, datagrid

I have a form with a data grid view and text boxes in C# WPF.
I get data from MySql Database using the search option based on name and Lastname on my fields.

```
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM  owners WHERE name='" + namesearch + "' OR last_name= '" + lastnamesearch + "'", conn);
```

and I bind some of the basic data like Name, Lastname, phone, national id into my Datagrid.

```
            <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn  Header="" Width="3" IsReadOnly="True" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=name}" Header="نام" Width="150" IsReadOnly="True" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=last_name}" Header="نام خانوادگی" Width="150" IsReadOnly="True" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=national_code}" Header="کد ملی" Width="200" IsReadOnly="True" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=father_name}" Header="نام پدر" Width="100" IsReadOnly="True" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=mobile}" Header="شماره همراه" Width="150" IsReadOnly="True" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
```

now I want to have this option: when I chose a row from data grid view rows, all the data I get with my query command before, just appear in text boxes, for example, the name goes to TexboxName last name goes to TexboxLastname, and also all other data I get but did not show in Datagrid view.
these are the fields I have on my table

[image]

I have a text box for each one of them
sorry for my bad English I hope you understand.

Comment: something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/44656041/1506454 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could bind the `TextBox` to the `SelectedItem` property of the `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dg" ... />

<TextBox x:Name="TexboxName" Text="{Binding SelectedItem.name, ElementName=dg}" />
```

Comment: The problem is i did not bind all the datas into the DataGrid.  only name and last name are bind into DataGrid l, for example there is a search box for name when someone search John, all the results of Johns (name, lastname and id) will appear into DataGrid and if i chose one of them the rest of the feilds (phone, address, birthday and...) Appear into text boxes.

Comment: Tha's why you should bind to the `SelectedItem` property of the `DataGrid` (see my edit). It returns the object that has all those properties/columns even if you only see a subset of them in the `DataGrid`.

Comment: I got it man, it worked, thanks for help, you make my day <3