# WPF Datagrid ERROR: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.'

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid, selecteditemchanged

I already searched for a solution on this topic. However, I was unable to find one. I trying to implement the solution answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121186/datagrid-get-selected-rows-column-values), however when adding a new row to the datagrid, I get "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.'" error. after  the new row was inserted and the program returned to the previously selected row before inserting a new value.

```
private void Datagrid_Registro_SelectedCellsChanged(object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
{
Registro.RegistroItems row =(Registro.RegistroItems)Datagrid_Registro.SelectedItems[0];

textbox_DocIdentidad.Text = row.DocumentoIdentidad;
comboBox_Ubicaciones.SelectedItem = row.AreaDestino;
textbox_CarnetAsignado.Text = row.CarnetAsignado;
}
```

Comment: Ask yourself - what happens on the first line of code when I de-select all of the items and the size of the SelectedItems list is 0?

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the right direction. I´ve solved the problem using an if statement evaluating the selectedItems.count property not equal to 0. @hoodaticus